# why does python add 2 elements to a list when I only want it to do once?

Tags: python

this is my code

```
from keyboard import *

charList = []

while True:

    charList.append(read_key())

    print(charList)
```

and for some reason when I press a key it adds to chars although I pressed it only once
and if I use the pop() function it doesnt add the chars at all
so python only allows me to add 0 or 2 elements at the same time
how do I fix?

Comment: When you press and release a key, that's two events, and events are what `read_key` looks for: *"Blocks until a keyboard event happens, then returns that event's name or, if missing, its scan code."* https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardread_keysuppressfalse

Answer (score 1):

`read_key()` returns both key up and key down events. So you're adding to the list when they press the key, and again when they release it. Check the event type so you only record one of them.

```
while True:
    ev = read_key()
    if ev.event_type == 'up':
        charList.append(ev)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you try to hold the key, you will realize, that the function `read_key()` returns at keyboard events. Such as `Button press`, `Button hold` or `Button release`. If you set a breakpoint inside the loop you will be fast enough to not get the `Button release` event and the list will append those elements only once. You should differentiate between the event types to resolve this issue.